# sdkman installation fails on raspberry pi

Tags: bash, java, raspberry-pi, jdk

I am trying to use SDKMAN to install java 17 on raspberry pi and the installation seems to work at first, it makes an initial download, but then it intends to `Installing script cli archive...` and it fails at the download portion of that step (see log below). Any help is greatly appreciated!! Sorry if I'm missing information, I'm a noob with this :)

```
Looking for a previous installation of SDKMAN...
Looking for unzip...
Looking for zip...
Looking for curl...
Looking for sed...
Installing SDKMAN scripts...
Create distribution directories...
Getting available candidates...
Prime platform file...
Prime the config file...
Installing script cli archive...
* Downloading...
######################################################################## 100.0%
* Checking archive integrity...
* Extracting archive...
* Copying archive contents...
* Cleaning up...

Installing script cli archive...
* Downloading...
#=#=#
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
'curl --fail --location --progress-bar "${SDKMAN_SERVICE}/broker/download/native/install/${SDKMAN_NATIVE_VERSION}/${SDKMAN_PLATFORM}" > "$sdkman_zip_file"': command failed with exit code 22.
```